# Sony Vaio Laptop loses wireless connectivity after few minutes

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, internet, ip, sony-vaio

I have a problem with my laptop. My laptop loses its internet connectivity randomly.
Sometimes it's okay for an hour but usually the problem occurs after 5 min.

When I run these commands, I can continue using the internet:

```
ipconfig /release   
ipconfig /renew
```

If I turn my wireless off and on, the problem isn't solved. I have a MacBook Pro and it doesn't have any problem. I use Linksys E2000 as an wireless access point.

My computer is Sony Vaio SA21GX  running Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Is there anything in the windows system log or on the AP's log (if you can access it). Have you changed anything in the Vaio's wireless setting? And finally, is it the same with other APs?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a workaround, since I don't know what the reason is:
Take a look at the WiFi LED in front. Pay attention if it turns off after couple minutes. If it does, go to Sony Vaio Wireless Manager. It is located in the task bar, next to the clock. Looks like a two grey arrows in opposite directions. Open this one and click the square button next to WLAN. This will turn on the WiFi adapter - LED should become green. Done!